# Podfile troubles

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods

I installed the latest cocoapods and ran pod init in my project. I opened up the file manually with textedit and it looks something like this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, ‘7.0’

pod ‘Wit’,  ‘~> 1.1.1’
```

However when i run pod install i get this error

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: /Users/me/projectfolder:4: syntax error, u
nexpected '~', expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
pod ‘Wit’,  ‘~> 1.1.1’
                ^
/Users/me/projectfolder:4: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot
pod ‘Wit’,  ‘~> 1.1.1’
                      ^. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.
```

Did i miss something crucial? I thought i followed the install instructions pretty closely but perhaps i forgot something. Any tips or hints would be appreciated. Not to familiar with cocoapods

Comment: Maybe try using the normal `'` instead of the curly one you have.

Comment: oh that seemed to work. Hmm seems like text edit has an issue with the braces.

Comment: I added it as an aswer. If it worked, then please accept it. :)

Comment: You can use this plugin to manage and correct your podfile. https://github.com/kattrali/cocoapods-xcode-plugin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe try using the normal ' instead of the curly one you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this cocoapods [plugin](http://github.com/kattrali/cocoapods-xcode-plugin) to manage and correct your podfile. It has autocorrection, search feature of cocoa pods

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using

platform :ios, '7.0'

Only the ' problem is there.